# Align equation ruin the equation numbering for all chapter '0' sections and appendix

Tags: equations, align

I am writing a thesis using the book document package, and I have a problem with the equation numbering for the appendix and other chapters where there are equations before the first section in the chapter. I have been reading around on the forum here and tried various possible solutions without luck, e.g.:

```
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
```

and

```
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{%
 \ifnum\value{subsection}=0 %
  \thesection
 \else
  \thesubsection
  \fi
 .\arabic{equation}%
}
```

among others. You can see pictures below of the problem.

[image]

[image]

After debugging quite a lot I have figured out that the align equation that can be seen in the code below (copy paste it into a blank latex document to see for yourself) is the problem. However, I have not been able to understand what is wrong with it. Do you have any idea about what I should change in the equation for it not to ruin the equation numbering for the rest of the thesis?

Here is some code that should give a overview of the situation:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[width=0.8\paperwidth, height = 0.85\paperheight]{geometry}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Norwegian letters
\thispagestyle{empty}                   % Remove page numbers from first page
\usepackage{tocloft}                    % Make dots in the toc               
\usepackage{amsmath, bm, array}                % Extra math functionality
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mhchem}                     % Write chemical equations
\usepackage{siunitx}                    % Typing of SI units
\usepackage{float}                      % Enables use of H-specific in images
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}   % References in toc
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{subcaption,ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is the first chapter}

\section{First section in first chapter}

\begin{equation}
\label{reflection-coefficient-as}
A = a \cdot x
\end{equation} 

\begin{align}
\chi_{S}^{e,1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \begin{bmatrix}
     u_{\bm{k}}, v_{\bm{k}}
\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}
     -1 \\ \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
-u_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ u_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ -v_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ v_{\bm{k}} 
\end{bmatrix} \text{, } & \chi_{S}^{e,-1} &=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
     u_{\bm{k}}, v_{\bm{k}}
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
     1 \\ \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
u_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ u_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ v_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ v_{\bm{k}}  
\end{bmatrix} \text{, } \nonumber  \\ \nonumber  \\ 
\chi_{S}^{h,1} &= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
     v_{\bm{k}}, u_{\bm{k}}
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
     -1 \\ \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
-v_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ v_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ -u_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ u_{\bm{k}} 
\end{bmatrix} \text{, and } & \chi_{S}^{h,-1} &= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
     v_{\bm{k}}, u_{\bm{k}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
     1 \\ \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
v_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ v_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ u_{\bm{k}} \\ \\ u_{\bm{k}}
\end{bmatrix} \text{.}
\end{align} \nonumber 


\chapter{This is the second chapter}

\begin{equation}
\label{reflection-coefficient-as}
A = a \cdot x
\end{equation} 

\begin{equation}
\label{reflection-coefficient-as}
A = a \cdot x
\end{equation} 

\section{Section Chap 2}

\begin{equation}
\label{reflection-coefficient-as}
A = a \cdot x
\end{equation} 

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{equation}
A = x c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A = x c
\end{equation}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{equation}
A = x c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A = x c
\end{equation}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! The problem is `\nonumber` after `\end{align}`. That is, you have the combination `\end{align} \nonumber`. Just remove `\nonumber` (or move it *into* the `align` environment if you intend not to number this equation).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `align` environment but the fact that you have a `\nonumber` *after*, i.e. outside of, it. If you either remove the `\nonumber` or move it before `\end{align}`, the equation numbering will be consistent.

[image]